# Orderby Desc in Eloquent, Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a query 3 tables are joined together, I want to order the results in Descending order from created_at in messages table, please help. Thank you.

controller:

```php
 return new AllChats(Chat::latest('created_at')->whereHas('messages')->with(['messages.users', 'users' =>
        function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', '!=', Auth::id());
        }])->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
            $query->where('id', '=', Auth::id());
        })->get());
```

Display the results in desc order but from messages.created_at??

Answer (score 1):

You need to just add the **->orderBy** on your ***created at*** field in your query.

```
return new AllChats(Chat::latest('created_at')->whereHas('messages')->with(['messages.users', 
    'users' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '!=', Auth::id());
    }])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '=', Auth::id());
    })->get());
```

[image: Sample Example]

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Comment: but I want to orderby from messages table

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
return new AllChats(Chat::latest('created_at')>>whereHas('messages',function($q){
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
 })->with(['messages.users', 'users' =>
    function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '!=', Auth::id());
    }])->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', '=', Auth::id());
    })->get());
```

Comment: doesnt do anything :( stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modified `withCount()`:

```php
$chats = Chat::withCount(['messages as latest_message' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('max(created_at)'));
    }])
    ->orderByDesc('latest_message')
    [...]
    ->get();
```

Comment: will try and let you know, but messages are connected to users table as well??